# Deploy as War: How not to override binary files , stored in models via Blob type

Tags: playframework

Everytime i deploy my play 1.2.5 app as a war ,pictures which are saved in models via the Play Blob type are deleted. Can prevent this behavior ?

Comment: Save the files in the regular filesystem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to store your images somewhere else because they will actually be deleted with each new deployment. And, if you have multiple deployments for scaling purposes, you will run into problems.

I put my images on Amazon S3, which was suggested to me by two hosting providers. It is actually pretty easy. Just set up an account with Amazon, and add this to your application.conf file:

```
s3.bucket=your-bucket-name-you-must-create-this-on-amazon
aws.access.key=the-key-which-you-get-from-amazon
aws.secret.key=the-secret-key-you-get-from-amazon
```

You can install the play s3blobs plugin to upload and download images (play 1.x only)

Use Amazon Cloudfront for faster loading.